# “GlobalProcesserfld” will damage your computer

Tags: macos, finder, applications

From past few days whenever I switch on my Mac m1 air, I am getting a warning popup saying “GlobalProcesserfld” will damage your computer' along with two option 'OK' & 'Show in finder'. When I click ok it goes down but reappears after some seconds and when I hit show in finder it does not show anything.

How can I get rid of this problem ?

Comment: https://howtoremove.guide/globalprocesserfld-mac/ might help, or https://www.myantispyware.com/2022/01/16/how-to-uninstall-globalprocesser-app-extension-from-mac-virus-removal-guide/#howtoremove